# How to encrypt data in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to understand if there is a default encrypt/decrypt functions available in Tableau in any version(14/15/18).

Can we create customized function to encrypt/decrypt data?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by adding encryption?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2018, Tableau doesn't come with any Encrypt/Decrypt functions.

Here is a screenshot of all available type of functions in Tableau.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some of the database drivers for Tableau allow you to specify an encrypted connection to the database (so the data is encrypted in transit). Some of the same databases can store data in encrypted form(so the data is encrypted at rest).

These features vary depending on the functionality of the data source.

So if you are talking to a text file, you don’t have encryption options, but most of the major databases do to a degree — maybe with SSL in transit. You can set up a virtual private database with Oracle for instance.

You asked about a function for encrypting data. Tableau doesn’t have a specific function beyond what I’ve described above, but you can also use the SCRIPT_STR() function and its cousins to call functions in R, Python or Matlab - so you can call an external encryption function if desired.